# how to save change from split content of text

Tags: php, split, tokenize, information-retrieval

I've managed to cut the string a sentence into a word. but the new results can be viewed in the browser when the program runs. but these results can not change the condition of the strings in the original text file. I want the contents of the original text file identical to compile the results in the browser. Well how ya how to store the results of the pieces of the word to the text file? in this case stored in notepad with a .txt extension.

To cut the text I use the following php code:

```
$width = strlen($openfile)/28000;
$wrapped = wordwrap($openfile, $width,'<br>');

//echo $wrapped;
$stringedit=str_replace(" ", "<br>", $openfile);
echo $stringedit;
```

result from browser is like this

[image]

Comment: Are willing to download this to .txt extension or replace original file with the $stringedit text?

Comment: replace original file then can using $stringedit text. so from original file want edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for it problem is like this ,it is 100% work:

```
 <?php
   $array_filename = glob('simpantoken/*.txt');
   foreach ($array_filename as $fileteks)
   {
    $stringteks = file_get_contents($fileteks); 
    $konversi = strtolower($stringteks);
    $jenistandabaca = array(',', '!', '?', '.', ':',';', '-');
    $hapustandabaca = str_replace($jenistandabaca,'',$konversi);
    $hapustandabaca = trim(preg_replace('/[^0-9a-z]+/i','', $konversi)); 
    $hapustandabaca = preg_replace('/[^a-z\d]+/i', '', $konversi);
    $hapustandabaca = preg_replace('/[^\w]+/','',$konversi);
    $hapustandabaca = preg_replace('/\W+/','',$konversi);
    $replacespasi = str_replace(" ", PHP_EOL, $konversi);
    $konversistring = explode("/", $konversi); 
    $array = preg_split('/[\pZ\pC]+/u', $konversi);
    $ubahkarakter = str_replace(" ", '<br/>', $konversi);
    if(strpos($konversi,' ') >  0)
    {    
      echo "ada spasi";
    }
     else
    {
        echo "tidak ada spasi";
     }
       $handle = fopen($fileteks, 'w');
       fwrite($handle, $replacespasi);
       fclose($handle);
      }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
file_put_contents ( $fileName, $stringedit); //here filename indicates the name/path of source file.
```

Comment: I have tried but to no avail. Text files can not be changed and still can not be edited. so the wording is still as usual paragraph is not the result token as it appears in the browser.

Comment: Remember that browser and notepad application does not treat text same manner. <br> will only work in browser where text editor search `\n` for new line. Also check if your php have proper write permission on that directory. First check `$fileName` is created or not. If yes open it in text editor and check if you see any <br> tag.

Comment: so that I can get the results create a file and write it when I opened the notepad text editor written only <br/>. only. whereas the content of the target file does not appear at all as it appears in the browser. nah how ya solution? I want to make tampilah in notepad exactly like the browser. I am also confused about the use of the split function in php. who knows whether the split function can not, as long as it still fails premises split function